# Redirect of WebRequest in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, httpwebrequest, asp.net-core-2.0

I wrote the following program in C# using .NET 4.7.1:

```
var req = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(myUrl);
req.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
var rsp = req.GetResponse();
Console.WriteLine(rsp.Headers["Location"]);
```

The site I am requesting from is returning a 301 response, and the "Location" header contains the URL to redirect to.

If I do the exact same thing using .NET Core 2.1, I will instead get a `WebException` thrown from the call to `GetResponse`. How can I avoid this?

Comment: *Don't* use HttpWebRequest to begin with. Use HttpClient and check the status code in the response

Comment: It's legacy code. So no not for me to choose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [this](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/23422), you need to trap it in `try/catch` block and inspect the `WebException`:

> If you set `AllowAutoRedirect`, then you will end up not following the
>   redirect. That means ending up with the 301 response.  `HttpWebRequest`
>   (unlike `HttpClient`) throws exceptions for non-successful (non-200)
>   status codes. So, getting an exception (most likely a `WebException`) is
>   expected. S**o, if you need to handle that redirect (which is HTTPS ->
>   HTTP by the way), you need to trap it in try/catch block and inspect
>   the WebException etc.** That is standard use of `HttpWebRequest`.
>
> That is why we recommend devs use `HttpClient` which has an easier use
>   pattern.

Something like this:

```
WebResponse rsp;

try 
{
   rsp = req.GetResponse();
}

catch(WebException ex) 
{
    if(ex.Message.Contains("301"))
        rsp = ex.Result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I pretty much figured it out while I was working on it, but I thought I'd post it here in case others run into the same issue.

The response is included as part of the exception that is throw, so I was able to get the same behavior as in .NET 4.7.1 by modifying my code to this:

```
var req = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(myUrl);
req.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
try
{
    var rsp = req.GetResponse();
    Console.WriteLine(rsp.Headers["Location"]);
}
catch (WebException e)
{
    var rsp = (HttpWebResponse) e.Response;
    if (rsp.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Moved ||
        rsp.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.MovedPermanently ||
        rsp.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Found)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(rsp.Headers["Location"]);
    }
    else throw;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using HttpWebRequest in the first place? Why not HttpClient.GetAsync?

Comment: .NET Core isn't legacy almost by definition. You are *converting* this code already. The workaround you posted here is *new* code, not legacy. By using HttpWebRequest you lose all HTTP-related benefits provided by .NET Core

Comment: Indeed, it's a conversion. And I'm sure you can appreciate that such a rewrite is not always desirable during a conversion.

Comment: You just found out why it is. You can't just use 8 year old code in a new runtime - HttpClient was introduced in 2012, along with async/await. The highest priority in ASP.NET Core was given to HttpClient and async/await. All this code could be replaced with a single `var response=await httpClient.GetAsync(...); response.Headers.Location ...`

Comment: "You can't just use 8 year old code in a new runtime" you have been able to all the way through .net framework.