# WebRequest behavour different between .net framework 4.8 and dotnet 5

Tags: .net, .net-5, .net-4.8

The following code throws and exception in dotnet 5 but does not in dotnet framework 4.8:

```
var req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(urlIncludingScheme);
req.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
var resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse()
```

In framework 4.8 a HttpWebResponse is returned with the StatusCode "Moved"
In dotnet core an exception is thrown with the message "The remote server returned an error: (301) Moved Permanently."

This makes me a little nervous about porting stuff from 4.8 to dotnet 5. I would expect this behaviour to remain unchanged in dotnet 5.

Can anyone tell if this is a bug or if it is actually the entention?

This is also discussed here: [Redirect of WebRequest in .NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52833655/redirect-of-webrequest-in-net-core)

But there is not discussion of the reason behind this difference.

Also, the discussion here does not explain if it is really the intention to make a breaking change in this scenario: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/23264

This was also reported as a bug here and solved, but doesnt seem to have been fixed: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/1074

Comment: `HttpWebRequest` isn't recommended anymore, `HttpClient` should be used instead

Comment: But that really doesnt answer WHY the behaviour has changed. The changed behaviour makes it impossible to port existing framework code without modifications. I have a dotnet standard repo used in both framework and dotnet core that now behaves differently in the two environments.

Comment: You can compare [.NET Core](https://source.dot.net/#System.Net.Requests/System/Net/HttpWebRequest.cs,f2ab2d685cb26f13) and [.NET FW](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/HttpWebRequest.cs,f2ab2d685cb26f13) sources to find, what was changed

Comment: Thanks again for your time, but this again does not answer my question of WHY the behaviour has changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that my project was running dotnet core 3.1.

framework 4.8: No exception

dotnet core 3.1: Exception thrown

dotnet 5: No exception - so the bug seems to have been fixed in dotnet 5.

I think it can be concluded that the exception was in fact unintended and has now been fixed.